# LiftWeb RESTHelper RestContinuation unit testing

Tags: scala, unit-testing, asynchronous, lift

I receive error when trying to test async request handlers that use `RestContinuation`. The error is simply: `ContinuationException: : Continuation`. I use `WebSpec` for testing.

I followed [this](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Mocking_HTTP_Requests) manual from 2012. But apparently it doesn't cover async use case. I also found another [post](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/liftweb/139vc86715/lift-unit-testing-restcontinuation-async) from 2013 where it is said that async testing is not supported. So has anyone by the end of 2016 figured out how to write tests for async request processing?

`liftVersion = 2.6.3
scalaVersion = 2.11.7
specs2Version = 2.3.11`

Answer (score 0):

In order to short circuit the request / response process, Lift throws a ContinuationException when you initiate a continuation.  It seems like your test framework is catching that exception and reporting it as an error.  If you can configure the test to ignore it, you'll solve that problem.  If you are looking to test the full request / response cycle of a RestContinuation though, that would be a bit trickier, since they occur on different threads.